# Организация ЧПУ htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, php

Ребята есть такой 
адрес
http://myshop.local/render/?file=/storage/books/PDF/test.pdf&id=12
 Вот правило .htaccess , не приходит параметр  file

```
 RewriteRule /render/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /render/?$1=$2&$3=$4&%{QUERY_STRING} [NS,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

В урл строке после render 5 блоков, а в правиле 4 блока. Строка не соответствует.

Comment: я думаю, `query_string` отбросится при парсинге, и там вообще не будет рерайта.